# Web.config: Escape quotes for password in provider connection string inside the connection string doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I have the following connection string

```
    <add name="EntitiesContainer"         
    connectionString="metadata=...;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbXYZ;User 
    ID=userxyz;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"         
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

My problem is, that I can't use quotes inside the provider connection string password. 
I tried to escape the password based on several posts on stack overflow and Mladen Prajdić Blog: https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/2008/10/21/different-ways-how-to-escape-an-xml-string-in-c/

I tried to escape a password like 'hello"World' with " with &quote, with System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape, with XMLWriter,  System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape and with System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode().

I guess that the problem lies in the fact, that I have an encapsulated string(provider connection string) inside the connection string.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `&amp;quot;`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  know how a value will be encoded in web.config:

- Go to Administrative Tools => IIS Manager
- Open the Site and any Web App Folder with web.config  or without(will be created)
- Go to  Feature view from the right: Open  Application Settings or Connection Strings 
  View and add or modify related value and save.
- Open the web.config through File Explorer and look at the saved value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a good advice! Unfortunately, it doesn't work, even if I write the password in the provider connection string(substring) via IIS.

Comment: What is the problem?